# How to implement Marketo tracking code

Tags: tracking, visitors

I'm investigating how to implement Marketo tracking visitor, email, white-paper, webinar,...
I have research about it, but i just know install script munchkin, but i don't know how to get it works?
Anybody could help me understand more about it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to insert the marketo "munchin api" script into the footer of your document as you would with Google analytics.

```
<script src="http://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>mktoMunchkin("YOUR ID HERE");</script>
```

You can get this code by logining into Marketo, going to "admin" in the top right, than going to "munchkin setup" in the left navigation bar.  You can will see your code which you can copy and paste into the footer.  This is all outlined on [this marketo setup guide](http://marketo.force.com/articles/MarketoPKBArticle?id=kA050000000KyqX).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Marketo developer evangelist here. We document [how to implement Munchkin](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/lead-tracking-munchkin-js/), which is Marketo's tracking code, on our [developer's site](http://developers.marketo.com/).